# Interactions in Parallel Views

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using a custom view from a third party framework. It has multiple iteractions/gestures in it like zooming, touch, etc. I want to create a UIView that has two parallel subviews of this custom view. Whenever you do any interaction on one subview like panning, it should do the exact same thing to the other subview. How would I go about implementing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add two UIViews of these custom views to your .xib and create a strong property to them. If they have delegates that allow you to detect the gestures you will be able to change the UI on one view if user interacts with the another.

Comment: I am new to iOS development so I am a bit confused. Are you saying that I should create a new delegate class, and when I do, how would I "forward" along all possible interactions?

Comment: No, don't create a new delegate. The views that you are using to detect gestures etc you must've implemented their delegate methods in your code file. You just need to set your main view as their delegate like:

`view1.delegate = self; 
view2.delegate = self;`

and then when one of them is tapped a delegate method like this would be called:

`-(void) viewWasTapped:(View *theView)`
`{`
    `//code to detect which view was tapped and what to change/show in the other view.`
`}`

Perhaps it will be better if you can share some of your code of the .m file